# Pycharm, importError no module name, when using os.system

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm, xlrd

I'm building in Pycharm a script (let's call it **script1**) that calls another script (let's call it **script2**) that take parameters as input

**script2** is using in it `xlrd` (`import xlrd`)
when I run **script2** manually and give it the needed parameters, it works very well

**script1**, calls **script2** (using `os.system()`) as follow:

```
os.system("python script2 -param1 ..")
```

and I get this error:

> from file script2
>
> import xlrd
>
> ImportError: No module named 'xlrd'

does anyone know how to fix it ? or make it work correctly ?

I made sure of the parameters I give as input, they are right 
and xlrd is defined in project interpreter

Thanks a lot

Comment: does this error happens only in pycharm? when you run script1 manually does it work, or you get the same error? if it doesnt work than pycharm has nothing to do with it

Comment: @DorElias, when I run script2 from pycharm it works very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably calling the wrong python.  If running `python script2...` from the command line works, use `where python` to get the full path and use it when calling `os.system`, for example:

```
os.system("c:\pythons7\python script2 -param1 ..")
```

(BTW - [It is recommended to replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) `os.system` with `subprocess.call` or some other subprocess function)

Comment: that worked!, I think it was causes because I have 2 installations

Comment: Thanks alot, I will also consider changing the `os.system` to `call`, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both files are in the same folder.  Do you have more than one installation/virtualenv of python?

A better option to ruse python code is defining functions and importing them:

```
#script2.py
import xlrd
def foo():
    print("I AM IN FOO NOW!")

#script1.py
import script2
script2.foo()
```

If yo are sure about calling script2 in a different process, consider using `subprocess.check_output` as a somewhat better API.

Comment: yes, they are in the same folder
I have 2 installations of python, python2.7 and python3
and I don't want to use function, I want to call script2 from script1

Answer (score 0):

Something that has helped me fix this issue in the past is appending the main file path at the top  of the script you are running through os.system

```html
import sys
# for
sys.path.append('/home/user/your_folder_with_python_scripts')
```